# Catastrophic backtracking issue solution

Tags: regex

I am having below regex pattern and getting catastrophic backtracking issue while testing.

my regex is:

```
(\s|\S)*((\%3C)|<)((\%2F)|\/)*[a-zA-Z0-9\%]+((\s|\S)*)+((\%3E)|>)(\s|\S)*
```

testing with string:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<fdslkjdskldsj dsfdlskhfdskhds dskfhdskjfhdsjkfhhaskdfffffshs
```

Please suggest me solution what wrong I have done in my regex pattern.

Comment: Can you please tell us what your regex is supposed to be doing?  And then show us sample data we can use to test it?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3791827

Comment: here is sample string <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<fdslkjdskldsj dsfdlskhfdskhds dskfhdskjfhdsjkf ds d sdkjlfgsdkjlhdsklf ds ds hsdfhds dsfds ds ds ds dsfdsfhdsi;hds ds dsfdjkshdskj fds dsh dskjfhdskjfh ds fds; dshds;kfh d ds gdfdsfs.

Comment: What programming language or tool? What are you trying to match?

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of this regex/sample is?

Comment: hi i m using java as programming language and eclipse tool.This expression is written by someone else earlier in my team so i m not sure what it is matching.i am having one screen which is having comment section and in that comment section this regex is used .so when i click on save button of the screen it keep moving and not getting saved.

Comment: @MayankSahay It looks like the person was trying to match HTML tags in either a normal (eg. </a>) or URL-encoded form (eg. %3C%2Fa%3E)

Answer (score 0):

The original regex seems to be trying to match simple HTML tags - either in plain text or URL-encoded form – without attributes that are embedded in multi-line text. eg `This is some <b>bolded</b> text.`

If so, then something like this:

```
(?i)[\s\S]*?((?:<|%3C)(?:\/|%2F)?[a-z\d]+(?:>|%3E))[\s\S]*?
```

would capture the tags within the text (and wouldn't fail when given the input you provided.)

Explained bit by bit, here's how it works:

```
(?i)        -- makes the regex case insensitive
[\s\S]      -- is an atom to match any character - even newlines
*?          -- match 0 or more, but as few as possible, of the previous atom
(           -- start a group that captures all matches until the closing )
(?:         -- start a group that doesn't capture it's contents
<|%3C)      -- match either a < or %3C (which is the URL-encoded version of <)
(?:\/|%2F)? -- optionally match a / or %2F
[a-z\d]+    -- match one or more letters or numbers
(?:>|%3E)   -- match the closing tag
)           -- close the open group
```

Comment: ..yes it is working after removing (\s|\S)* .I mean i make my expression like (\s|\S)*((\%3C)|<)((\%2F)|\/)*[a-zA-Z0-9\%]+((\%3E)|>)(\s|\S)*.So my concern is the expression will give same output as earlier and also it will remove backtracking issue???

Comment: Hi @MayankSahay - each `(\s|\S)*` is a problem, not just the one that you removed.